# How can I put an arrow function in a console.log statement so that it prints out the return value of the arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I am learning E6+, so please be kind.

There is probably a very simple explanation for this, but I can't figure it out.  How can I put an arrow function in a console.log statement so that it prints out the return value of the arrow function.  I've tried the following and they aren't working:

```js
console.log("1. Print 100:", () => {
  10 * 10;
});
console.log("2. Print 100:" + () => (10 * 10));
console.log("3. Print 100:", () => 10 * 10);
console.log(`4. Print 100: + ${ () => {10*10;} } `);
```

Comment: None of these functions are being called. Instead it will output their string value `(() => {10*10;}).toString()`

Answer (score 3):

By calling the function as an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
console.log("1. Print 100:", (() => 10 * 10)());
```

As written, your code just tries to print the function itself, instead of the return value.

Comment: Got it.  I had tried: 

console.log("1. Print 100:", ( () => 10 * 10) );  

but not the correct immediate invocation format:

console.log("1. Print 100:", (() => 10 * 10)() );